# Forgot Password - redirect to an external site after completion

Tags: experience-cloud, forgot-your-password

We have an external customer website and we are setting up Sslesforce as the identity provider for SSO.

The regular flow is working correctly and works as follows:

1. User is on external website and is redirected to a Salesforce experience site as they are not logged in. (Client Id etc passed in redirect)
2. The user logs into the experience site
3. The user is redirected back to the external website with an authorization code
4. The external website does a post request to Salesforce which returns an access token and an identity token

This follows the flow outlined here and is working perfectly.
https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.remoteaccess_oauth_web_server_flow.htm&type=5

However, if at (2) the user clicks forgotten password on the experience site login page the user receives a link for password reset. They can then click this and change the password which works fine. However, after the password is changed they are now logged into the experience site instead of being redirected back to the external website.

How can we fix this so that after password reset the user is redirected back to the external website as it should be?

Comment: Do you use the experience site for anything but login?

Comment: Just logging in, nothing else.

Comment: Could you not therefore set a meta header redirect to your standard SSO return URL in the home page for the digital experience?

Comment: The redirect from the home page is all that you need, it's not out of the box. A more elegant but quite a bit more effort option is to use the [headless Forgot Password flow](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=release-notes.rn_experiences_headless_identity_pointer.htm&type=5&release=242) that is new in Spring '23

Comment: Redirect sounds like a good option I can try. 

@PhilW I tried to do a meta header redirect using:
<meta http-equiv="Refresh" content="0; URL=https://example.com/" />.

But this throws an error and seems not allowed as per:
https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.community_builder_page_head.htm&type=5

Comment: OK, so you might need to create an LWC that does the redirect for you and drop it in the page (we've done this before).